# Random number of questions on game over screen on each run in arithmetic quiz game

Tags: java

I'm developing a game where the player does random types of basic arithmetic questions. When it displays the results when the game ends, it will display a message: "You answered %d questions with %d total attempts, your score is %.1f%%". However, when the user enters a value that is not an integer for their desired number of questions, the number of attempts made and the number of questions is different every time. The number of questions and the number of attempts is always the same, so it will always output a score of 100%. Inversely, when the user does enter an integer the first time they are prompted for the number of questions they want to do, the output for the percentage score at the end of the game will be "0.0%" if they answer incorrectly even once.

I have tried using try blocks inside of the try block to catch a NumberFormatException, as this only happens if they enter a value that is not an integer.

```
public static void randomArithmeticGame()
{
    //RNG
    int randNum;
    boolean isValidInput = false;
    boolean isInRange = false;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the random arithmetic test", "Welcome", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Addition a;
    Subtraction s;
    Multiplication m;
    int ans;
    while(!isValidInput)
    {
        try
        {
            int numberOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many questions would you like? (-1 to return to main menu)", "How many questions", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
            while(!isInRange)
            {
                if(numberOfQuestions == -1)
                {
                    //get out of loop if user enters -1 and go to bottom of block
                    break;
                }
                //do this while the number is not in range
                if(numberOfQuestions > 10 || numberOfQuestions < 1)
                {
                    //tell user that the number entered is out of range
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of questions is not between 1 and 10, Please try again.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    try
                    {
                        numberOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many questions would you like? (-1 to return to main menu)"));
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException exception)
                    {
                        //catch exception
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number entered was not an integer. Please try again.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //if number is in range then break out of loop
                    isInRange = true;
                    isValidInput = true;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++)
            {
                randNum = (int)(Math.random()*3 + 1);
                if(randNum == 1)
                {
                    //generate addition if rng is 1
                    a = new Addition();
                    ans = a.getAnswer();
                    a.checkAnswer(ans);
                }
                if(randNum == 2)
                {
                    //generate subtraction if rng is 2
                    s = new Subtraction();
                    ans = s.getAnswer();
                    s.checkAnswer(ans);
                }
                if(randNum == 3)
                {
                    //generate multiplication if rng is 3
                    m = new Multiplication();
                    ans = m.getAnswer();
                    m.checkAnswer(ans);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            //catch exception
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number entered was not an integer. Please try again.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    int finalScoreQuestionNum = Addition.getNumberOfAdditionQuestions() + Subtraction.getNumberOfSubtractionQuestions() + Multiplication.getNumberOfMultiplicationQuestions();
    int finalScoreResponseNum = Addition.getNumberOfResponses() + Subtraction.getNumberOfResponses() + Multiplication.getNumberOfResponses();
    double finalScorePercentage = (finalScoreQuestionNum/finalScoreResponseNum)*100.0;
    String finalScoreMessage = String.format("You answered %d questions with %d total attempts, your score is %.1f%%", finalScoreQuestionNum, finalScoreResponseNum, finalScorePercentage);
    //show user how mantt questions they did, number of attempts they made, as well as their final score and percentage
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, finalScoreMessage, "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

The output should show the number of questions the user did, the number of attempts they made, and their percentage score. But the percentage and the number of attempts are the same only if the user doesn't enter an integer for the number of questions they want to do at the beginning of the game.

Comment: firstly, you only have one each of the `Addition`, `Subtraction` and `Multiplication` object.  Secondly if for example `randNum` is never `2` you will never have a `Subtraction` Object.

Comment: the `randNum` variable is used to select which one to generate

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are dividing `int` in `finalScoreQuestionNum/finalScoreResponseNum`.

If some value 0 < x < 1 results in the division. It will be 0. That's why you are always getting 0% when one of it is wrong i.e 99/100 will yield 0.
The decimal part is ignored.

Comment: You mean like this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes. like that.